# is it possible to count cell in Violin plot in seurat?

Tags: rna-seq, scrnaseq

[image]

I tried to quantify the number of cells of Fzd9+ Macrophage.

how can I know the cell count?

thank you

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Does @haci's response answer your question? If so please mark it as "accepted". The question appears to contain very little detail and is easy for a misunderstanding to occur in these situations.

Answer (score 3):

This can be a good starting point: `table(your_seurat_object@meta.data$the_column_that_has_the_labels_of_interest)`

Basically you will be counting the number of rows (each single cell is a row) in the `meta.data` slot of your Seurat object for each level of your column of interest (for example cell type annotations).